# data defined properties 2 different functions

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have values which are from 0 - 21000. Now i want to display only the values above 10 and the number 21000 should be displayed as 2,1%. I want to use the data defined properties. My first assumption was:

```
"values">10
CASE 
WHEN "values"=21000 THEN 2,1%
ELSE "values"
END
```

This does not work though because i just can´t click OK in the data-defined properties. The Error says:

```
syntax error, unexpected CASE, expecting $end.
```

Is there anything else to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (presuming it is for labelling) with an expression:

```
CASE
WHEN "values">10 AND "values"<>21000 THEN "values"
WHEN "values"=21000 THEN '2.1%'
END
```

You can also use a rule-based labelling, with:

```
"values">10
```

And as a label:

```
CASE
WHEN "values"=21000 THEN '2.1%'
ELSE "values"
END
```

[image]

Cheers,

Comment: I can click ok now and everything above 10 is displayed, which is fine, but the 21000 is still not displayed as 2,1%. Any advise? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you've used the exact formulas? It's working on my qgis 2.18.1...
How about the second method?

Comment: The inverted commas around the 2.1% are important. '2.1%'

Comment: Somehow it still does not show the 21000 as 2.1%. I can´t tell you why and i´ve done everything like you told me. Even as rule based labelling it won´t work. I thank you very much for taking your time!

Comment: Maybe try with inverted commas for all values: '10' and '21000'. If you pass me a subset or your data I will have a look.